# xsl apply-templates with condition test

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have been trying to add tests to my xsl:apply templates elements but I keep getting an error that says "The expression does not evaluate to a node-set."  I am wondering if someone could point out what I am doing wrong to point me in the right direction.

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<catalog>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <band>
            <guitar>Joe</guitar>
            <drums>Rachel</drums>
            <bass>Mike</bass>
        </band>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <band>
            <guitar>Cat</guitar>
            <drums>Paul</drums>
            <bass>Bobby</bass>
        </band>     
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <band>
            <guitar>Eric</guitar>
            <drums>Bill</drums>
            <bass>Jason</bass>
        </band>     
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- DWXMLSource="Catalog.xml" -->
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet  [
<!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;">
<!ENTITY copy   "&#169;">
<!ENTITY reg    "&#174;">
<!ENTITY trade  "&#8482;">
<!ENTITY mdash  "&#8212;">
<!ENTITY ldquo  "&#8220;">
<!ENTITY rdquo  "&#8221;"> 
<!ENTITY pound  "&#163;">
<!ENTITY yen    "&#165;">
<!ENTITY euro   "&#8364;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="catalog">
<xsl:apply-templates select="cd" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
  <p style="color:red;">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title = 'Empire Burlesque'" />
  </p>
  <p style="color:blue;">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="artist = 'Bob Dylan'" />
  </p>
  <p style="color:green;">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="band/guitar = 'Joe'" />
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
Title: <xsl:apply-templates />    
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="artist">
Artist: <xsl:apply-templates />   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="band/guitar">
Guitar: <xsl:apply-templates />   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result I was expecting is:

```
Title: Empire Burlesque

Artist: Bob Dylan

Guitar: Joe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the template

```
<xsl:template match="cd">
  <p style="color:red;">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title = 'Empire Burlesque'" />
  </p>
  <p style="color:blue;">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="artist = 'Bob Dylan'" />
  </p>
  <p style="color:green;">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="band/guitar = 'Joe'" />
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

This illustrates both a syntax issue and a logic issue.

Syntax first:  given a cd element as the current node, the expression "title" evaluates to a node set.  The expression "title = 'Empire Burlesque'" evaluates to a Boolean.  If you want to apply templates to every title child that has the string value 'Empire Burlesque', you want to write something like "title[. = 'Empire Burlesque']".  Once you fix all three select expressions, you are going to get the output you expect.

Now, logic.

This template will be evaluated once for each cd element in the input.  So once you fix your select expressions, you are going to get the expected output, followed by

```
<p style="color:red;"/>
<p style="color:blue;"/>
<p style="color:green;"/>
<p style="color:red;"/>
<p style="color:blue;"/>
<p style="color:green;"/>
```

The first three empty paragraphs will be generated by the Bonnie Tyler CD, the second three by Dolly Parton.

If you're regarding HTML as a write-only language, this may not do any particular harm, but it's an unnecessary ugliness in your output.  Put your conditions in the right locations.

Comment: Thank you!  I updated the way the <xsl:template match="cd"> by adding <xsl:template match="cd[title='Empire Burlesque']">.  This works but after the final <p> tag all the remaining XML node values are printed onto the page.  Am I missing another conditional test?  I added the update to the original question.  Thanks again for taking the time to explain the flaw I had in my first try.

Comment: I see if I change <xsl:template match="cd[title='Empire Burlesque']"> to <xsl:template match="cd">, and apply the condition test on the following ti works :) 

<xsl:template match="catalog">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="cd[title='Empire Burlesque']" />
</xsl:template>

Comment: Good to see that you found a solution.  What was happening was this:  If you change the match pattern on your current cd template to match="cd[title = 'Empire Burlesque']", then the other cd elements are matched by the default template, which calls apply-templates on its children;  this in turn means that the text nodes for the children of the other cd elements are processed by the default template for text nodes, which prints out their string value.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I googled xslt default templates and see that now, but I was really caught by why those would display so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Condition is made in the way below:

```
<xsl:template match="cd">
  <p style="color:red;">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title[text()='Empire Burlesque']" />
  </p>
  <p style="color:blue;">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="artist[text()='Bob Dylan']" />
  </p>
  <p style="color:green;">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="band/guitar[text()='Joe']" />
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Using `[. = 'Joe']` is better than using `[text()='Joe']` (therefore downvoting). To see why, look what happens if the XML contains a comment: `<title>Empire<!--[sic]--> Burlesque</title>`. There are now two text nodes, neither equal to "Empire Burlesque", but a test on the string value still works.